# How to calculate the probability of multiple objects being next to each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is:
Let $F$ be the set of all functions from $\{1..n\} \to\{1..n\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ If all the functions in $F$ are laid out randomly in a straight line, what is the probability that at least 3 bijective functions are next to each other (touching), at least once?

I have started this partially, as (if I'm not wrong), there are $n^n$ functions in $F$ and there are $n!$ bijective ones I would assume. So the probability of a randomly selected one being bijective is $\frac{n!}{n^n}$.

Beyond that, I have no idea. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some of the question in the Related column may help here.

Comment: Just try to answer a more general question: if $N$ balls, $n$ of which are red, are laid out randomly in a line, what is the probability of at least $3$ consecutive red balls? In turn, to answer this general question, consider the complementary event.